# How can I prevent R6 classes to access non-existent members?

Tags: r, r6

R6 automatically sets to NULL anything I access on self

```
> x <- R6::R6Class("x", list(foo = function() { print(self$notexistent) }))
> xx <- x$new()
> xx$foo()
NULL
```

This means that if I make a typo in one access e.g. `results` instead of `result` it will use NULL instead of throwing an error. Is there a way to force the latter?

Comment: Have you tried `tryCatch()`?

Comment: @Sotos yes I always tryCatch before I accidentally mistype a variable.

Comment: Might not be what you're looking for, but how about writing a tiny getter function that throws you an error when the name isn't actually set on self?

Comment: `get(..., self)`

Comment: Oh, true, that exists. *facepalm

Comment: Is there no way of creating a R6 class that by default raises an exception? I think it's quite stupid to have to retrieve stuff with get every time

Comment: @StefanoBorini do you mean if you make a typo in the class definition or as a user?

Comment: @AllanCameron if in the class definition of a member function, I use a variable member on self that is not defined, I should get an error. not NULL.

Comment: when you try to reach an element that does not exist, `R` returns `NULL`. You can code so if `NULL` is returned, you get an error but it seems to me returning NULL when there is no element of the name is totally normal behaviour

Comment: @Cath it is not normal behavior at all. It's fundamentally wrong.

Comment: The `self` in an R6 function is an environment. The `$` operator for environments is a primitive, and as far as I can tell it can't be overwritten. Therefore you need to either use `get` or an explicit `is.null` check if you want an error to be thrown. Alternatively, define an operator other than `$` that you use on `self` that explicitly throws. For example, you could define a function called `self` that you use like `self(notexistent)`

Comment: let's say you find it wrong, probably because you're used to other languages' behaviours and I (probably along with several R users) find it normal

Comment: I guess it didn't occur to you that `R` may not be wrong, only you are using it wrong?

Comment: When reading [this blog post](https://stefanoborini.com/why-r-is-the-new-perl/) I think you should first yell at yourself for your poor understanding of the language instead of yelling a R being a poor language. I won't say R is the perfect language, but then again: none of the programming languages is perfect. Each programming language does have it's strong points and it's weaknesses. Python does, R does, any language does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `self` in an R6 function is an environment. The `$` operator for environments is a primitive, and as far as I can tell it can't be overwritten. By default this operator returns `NULL` rather than throwing an error if the right-sided operand isn't found in the environment, and this fact has to be explicitly handled by the caller.

This isn't so different from, say, the `[` operator in C++, which doesn't bounds check a vector. Unless you explicitly check your bounds, your program will crash. If you want to bounds check you need to use a different operator like `.at`: these will be safer, but will also slow your software down. It boils down to priorities. You either go fast or you change syntax and check.

Therefore if you would prefer bounds-checking behaviour from `self`, you need to write a different, safer accessor with different syntax.

```r
`%$%` <- function(env, member) {
  member <- deparse(substitute(member))
  ls <- eval(as.call(list(quote(ls), substitute(env))), 
                     envir = parent.frame())
  if(!member %in% ls) stop(member, " is not a member of this R6 class")
  eval(as.call(list(quote(`[[`), substitute(env), member)), 
       envir = parent.frame())
}

x <- R6::R6Class("x", list(foo = function() print(self%$%notexistent),
                           bar = function() print(self%$%baz),
                           baz = 1))
xx <- x$new()

xx$foo()
#> Error in self %$% notexistent : 
#>   notexistent is not a member of this R6 class 

xx$bar()
#> [1] 1
```

You may not like the fact that you can't use the `$` operator in this way, but that's the way R is. I think it's clear you don't like the language, and I can't change that, but until your plans to destroy it are realised, you can see it as a challenge...